# SQL Trigger is Not working

Tags: sql, t-sql, database-trigger

I have created the following trigger so that if any item in the Sales.OrderDetails table has a unitprice less than 10, it cannot have a discount greater than .5:

```
create trigger  Sales.tr_SalesOrderDetailsDML 
on Sales.OrderDetails
After insert, update
as
begin 
  if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 return ;

  set nocount on;    
  if  exists (select oi.orderid 
             from inserted as oi
             where oi.unitprice < 10.0 and oi.discount > 0.50)
  Throw 50002, 'Order can''t have discount more than 5 if unit price is less than 10', 10;

end;
go
```

When I insert the following row:

```
INSERT INTO Sales.OrderDetails (orderid,productid,unitprice,qty,discount)
VALUES (10249, 16, 9.00, 1, 0.90);
```

it accepts it, the trigger does not Throw the error despite the fact that it's unitprice is less than 10 and decount is bigger than 5.

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have multiple mistakes here.

1. Your trigger is an `after` trigger. meaning it will only be executed after the row was already inserted or updated.
2. You are stopping the trigger to be executed when rows are updated, with that `if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 return;`
3. This is the kind of thing you don't want triggers for, but a check constraint.

Alter your table to add a check constraint that will prevent the value of discount to be bigger then 5 when the unit price is less then 10.

```
ALTER TABLE Sales.OrderDetails
ADD CONSTRAINT CHK_UnitPriceAndDiscount   
CHECK (unitprice > 10 OR discount < 0.5)
GO
```

Comment: Like this : constraint Cons_PriceLessDicount
Check ( unitprice > 10 or dicount < 0.50); ?

Comment: I don't understand the comment. You can call the contstraint whatever you want, as long as it's a meaningfull name.

Comment: I have written the constraint code in the comment it can be add in alter code

Answer (score 1):

Check this line `if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 return ;` This will return immediately if affected rows is greater than 0... so the additional logic will not be executed. Replace with `if @@ROWCOUNT = 0`

Answer (score 1):

Remove `RowCount >0`,change it to

```
if (@@rowcount=0) return;
```

Answer (score 1):

it's not do statement under `if @@ROWCOUNT > 0 return ;` because `@@rowcount` greater than 0 then it return